# How can i access variables from my main.cpp in a seperate class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a variable named: int luckyNumber; in my main.cpp file. I need to access in in my gameLoopMachine.cpp to print it out but I seemed to have forgotten how. Do I need to do something when I prototype it? Any help is appreciated! thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variable as

```
extern int luckyNumber;
```

in `gameLoopMachine.cpp`. Though I wouldn't advise this as good design.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your variable into a function which returns a reference to a static local variable.

```
int &luckyNumber()
{
  static int number;
  return number;
}
```

You will be able to access the variable from everywhere and avoid any problems with static-initialization order.